# Non-invertible matrix and column vector : $AX = O_{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-equations

I am trying to solve this exercise:

> Let A be a matrix of size $n \times n$ and X a non-zero column matrix of size $n.$ Show that if there exists a matrix $X$ such that $AX = O_n,$ then $A$ is not invertible.

If I understood correctly, I have to show that $AX = O_n \implies$ that $A$ is not invertible, i.e. that there is no matrix $B$ such that $AB = I_n.$

I don't have much idea how to solve this problem, which way to go, so I tried to develop this product a little bit and I found :
$$AX =x_1 \pmatrix{a_{11} \\ \vdots\\ a_{n1}} + x_2 \pmatrix{a_{12} \\ \vdots\\ a_{n2}} + \cdot\cdot\cdot + x_i \pmatrix{a_{1i} \\ \vdots\\ a_{ni}} + \cdot\cdot\cdot + x_n \pmatrix{a_{1n} \\ \vdots\\ a_{nn}}$$

From here (I know it's not much ^^), I haven't found any ideas to show what I want. I can write a sum like $x_1 \cdot a_{11} + ... + x_n \cdot a_{1i} = 0$, but I don't see how this can be useful.

Thanks in advance for your help / advice!

Comment: **Hint :** If $A$ is invertible, what can you say about $A^{-1}AX$ ?

Comment: We can say that $A^{-1} A = I_n$, so $A^{-1}AX = X$ ?

Comment: Yes, and also, using that $AX=0$, we can say that......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can assume, by contradiction, that $A$ is invertible and $B$ is its inverse. Then $$X=BAX=BO_n=O_n,$$ which contradicts the assumption $X\neq O_n.$

Comment: That is a very good solution ! I just skipped that, but it is very clear to me now. Thanks a lot

Comment: You´re welcome, Lucas.